# Some mvc pages doesn't see silverlight in thinktecture server

Tags: silverlight, exception, model-view-controller

I have a very strange problem.
I would like to add some silverlight page to an action method in the Account controller (view for action method within it) , however when I navigate it gives me silverlight exception that it cannot download the silverlight.

But when I move it another controller (say Home controller view) it works well !!

I have checked existence of xap , MIME types in ISS  everything is well

Answer (score 0):

For some unknow reason I had to write

```
<param name="source" value="<% = Url.Content("~/ClientBin/TakingMyPicture.xap") %>"/>
```

rather than

```
<param name="source" value="~/ClientBin/TakingMyPicture.xap"/>
```